# Yakisugi (burning) pressure treated wood?

Tags: lumber, wood-finishing

Can you finish pressure treated wood with fire if it's treated with

- Alkaline Copper Quaternary (ACQ)
- Copper Azole (CA-B)

With a technique like [Yakisugi / shou sugi ban](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yakisugi)? Will these interfere with the longevity of the wood?

Comment: This sounds to go as deep or deeper than treatment.  Imagine the smoke would be badder than plain wood, worst long term health effects.  Remind me to move when doing it.

Comment: Yakisugi is scorched cypres. Cypres is naturally rot resistant, use untreated wood.

Answer (score 3):

I did a little searching, because CCA treated wood is what I'm most familiar with (don't burn!), and every source I found for ACQ says not to burn it.  Here is one source: https://www.ptw-safetyinfo.ca/en/alkaline-copper-quaternary-acq

> Do not burn treated wood. Preserved wood should not be burned in open fires, stoves or fireplaces.

The alternative treatments don't contain Arsenic, but they do contain pesticides and those aren't safe to burn.

The various treatments are forced into the wood under pressure, so if you are determined to do this with an appropriate respirator, I don't think it would affect longevity.  The end-grain on pressure treated lumber is routinely left exposed when the wood is cut, and it retains the benefits of the treatment.

A lot of pressure treated wood is shipped wet, and the boards in the middle of a bunk usually remain wet until sold.  To even test this and see if the resulting char is what you want you would need to buy boards and stack them on stringers outside for 3-4 weeks to fully dry (depending on location, of course).

Comment: They used to sell end cut paint/solution for PT wood, think the old green stuff , might be banned now.

Comment: Copper Green is the trade name of the end treatment available in California. And a caution about drying pt: if it isn’t stickered and stacked pretty aggressively (ie, lots of weight on top) it can twist and warp something fierce.

Comment: The treatment chemicals rarely penetrate the full depth of the lumber, even in the pieces rated for ground contact, so cuts exposing the former interior will rot significantly faster. That's why there exists "End-Cut Solution" and similar products.